# How to export System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Chart Chart to Word in C#

Tags: c#, charts

I have a windows form which shows charts as follows:

[image]

I need to export this chart in Microsoft word document. How to perform this in C# code.Is there any way without using any third party tool?

Comment: Have a look at [DrapToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_DrawToBitmap_System_Drawing_Bitmap_System_Drawing_Rectangle_). Once you have a Bitmap you can use the image in word.

Comment: You need to know which format you want to import there: PNG or, if your Workd can handle it one of the vector formats. If you go for a bitmap make sure to set a large enough dpi resolution, as screen look bad when printed.For this you can temporarily enlarge th chart..

Comment: I don't know which format will be better. I need to have a better solution.